# How to use CSS @property with scss?

Tags: css, sass, css-houdini

I want to declare a custom variable with a specific syntax e.g.:

```css
@property --colorPrimary {
  syntax: "<color>";
  initial-value: magenta;
  inherits: false;
}
```

So that I can animate the property, however this bit of code seems to be ignored by scss.

Comment: share the full code, the issue is probably somewhere else

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1jw72kuo/
It looks like maybe I just need to declare the `@property` at root level rather than inside `.foo`?

Comment: @ property is like @ keyframes. They cannot be nested inside selectors